# Lua: passing multiple results from function to table constructor

Tags: lua

I have stumbled on strange behaviour of lua. Code example:

```lua
function foo()
    local t = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
    return unpack(t)
end

function bar()
    local t = {'x', 'y'}
    return unpack(t)
end

b = { foo(), bar() }

for k,v in pairs(b) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Result of this code is:

```
1   a
2   x
3   y
```

So, results from `foo()` are all discarded except the first element. Question is, why some elements are discarded?
I have briefly checked lua 5.2 manual, but I don't see explanation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Question is, why some elements are discarded?

Because that's how Lua works. [Expressions that result in multiple values](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4) (function calls and `...`), when used in the context of a list of things (such as a table constructor or a function call argument list) will only add all of their values to that list if it is the *last* element of the list.

So:

```
{foo, ...}
```

Will put all of the varargs at the end.

```
{..., foo}
```

Will only put the first of the varargs into the table.

If you want to bundle multiple function calls like this, you have to use a function that will `table.insert` each element into the list individually.

Comment: How inconvenient. I hope, there were important purposes to make this part of language in such unintuitive way.
Anyway, thanks for the quick answer. Now I know that I haven't made some stupid little error.

Comment: Yes there are VERY important purposes. A function may return any number of results, and may return different number of results on different invocations. This is used to mark error conditions - in case of error you just return *nil*, *errorString*. Imagine you wanted to call `io.open` on multiple filenames - you can expect every element to be either *nil* or a file handle. If multiple results did expand, you would have to handle the special case of error strings suddenly appearing in the array. Also, the number of returned values cannot be known at compile time.